# Could not open avd_name.avd/cache.img

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtualization, android-virtual-device, android-6.0-marshmallow

When i run emulator, i get the following error:

> Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
>
> Output:
>   Hax is enabled
>   qemu-system-x86_64.exe: -drive if=none,index=1,id=cache,file={path_to_SDK}\SDK.android\avd{AVD_name}.avd/cache.img: could not open disk image {path_to_SDK}\SDK.android\avd{AVD_name}.avd/cache.img:
>
> Could not open '{path_to_SDK}\SDK.android\avd{AVD_name}.avd/cache.img':
>
> Invalid argument
>
> Hax ram_size 0x40000000
>
> HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
>   Error accepting connection, aborting

AVD specs are:

OS: Android 6.0 Google APIs

RAM: 1GB

Resolution:  1440x2560

Running on Android Studio 2.0 Beta 6, Windows 10.

Comment: i think there is some issue with image file

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Keep an eye out for a background qemu-system-i386.exe process running in the background that will be locking the cache.img file.

[image: Windows Task Manager - Background Emulator Process]

This might be still running from a previously failed emulator launch. Kill that using Task Manager and start again.

Comment: Had this issue in Visual Studio and killing this task (no emulators showed to be running) and restarting debug took care of the error.

Comment: When you look at the answers / comments for questios like this... a native .net developer wonders if they can ever reliably count on microshaft.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem already twice since I upgraded to Android Studio 2.0 on Windows 10. I use a preferred emulator in the Run/Debug configuration. Changing the Deployment Target Options in the configuration to Target: Show Device Chooser Dialog solved it for me. After choosing the same emulator instance in the dialog it started with no problem. Then I change back to the preferred emulator setting. Until the next time it breaks...

Hoping this helps.

Comment: How do you do the equivalent from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem in Windows 10.

Clearing temp and `%temp%` folder followed by a restart of machine solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, when I didn't notice that emulator is already running :)