# Android app is not launched in emulator in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I created an app in `Android studio`. It builds and runs on my phone but, When i run emulator it runs and shows the phone.

**The output:**

```
emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
qemu-system-i386.exe: -drive if=none,index=1,id=cache,file=C:\Users\one\.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_23_new.avd/cache.img: could not open disk image C:\Users\one\.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_23_new.avd/cache.img: Could not open 'C:\Users\one\.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_23_new.avd/cache.img': Invalid argument
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Please tell us which version of those apps you are using ? and tell us if you've tried something else before(Any tried solutions)?

Comment: The solution in this link worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/40789371/1582126

Comment: Answer in the other place with the similar question works for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/40789371/1582126

Answer (score 0):

It may be bad, but it´s working for me:
First, go to your SDK folder (i.e. %localappdata%\android\sdk)
Open the "tools" folder.
There you find an "emulator-crash-service.exe" file. Copy it to the same folder and rename it to "emulator64-crash-service.exe".
Go back to the SDK Folder and go to the subfolders   "extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\" and launch the "intelhaxm-android.exe" to install the HAXM driver manually.
Now create a new AVD and it should start.

Comment: I have emulator64-crash-service.exe and emulator-crash-service.exe in tools folder. What and where to copy ?

Comment: @ВладимирЛапенков..then just cut the emulator-crash-service.exe and paste in some different folder and try the next steps

Comment: @ВладимирЛапенков..when i got this problem in my side...somewhere i read to do this...and by doing this that time my problem was resolved...except this..I have no idea...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by:
 - redownloading Android x86 image (64bits/api23/google_apis in my case)
 - creating a new virtual device and choosing Nexus 5 instead of Nexus 4

I'm not sure if all steps are required.